# ActionScript 3 Bindable MetaData Tag without Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am just just curious as to whether the `[Bindable]` metadata tag in ActionScript 3 can only be used within the Flex framework, or can it be used in "regular" ActionScript projects where Flex isn't used?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think by default its a flex only thing. But I think if you point the project to the proper libraries you might be able to get it to work. I haven't tried it but would love to see if you get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://udon.nudoru.com/2011/01/07/nori-bindable-model/) it can be used only in the Flex framework. But there are ways to to have the same functionality in pure AS3.

Off-topic: why there is a php tag on this question?

Comment: Hi, Chris. Thanks for the response! I know I could do it in AS3, but I though perhaps the `[Bindable]` tag would be a nifty shortcut. As for the "php" tag, I didn't know how else to get my question to show-up on the homepage, unless I use a really popular tag, like "php".